# SSH connection slow over some networks

Tags: ssh

Can anyone tell me why sometimes when I connect by SSH to a linux server network (in my case), where the network connection from my remote location is of poor quality, why it is often unusable but it is still possible to use other services like http webpages or Skype which (relatively) still work quite well? I have always presumed that the ISP is applying some kind of prioritising. It seems mad to me that I can't send a few ASCII characters without waiting sometimes for 5 minutes. Yet as mentioned before, much bigger files can be sent and received by http during the same period. Can anything be done about it? It is a really important issue because it prevents me for working. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can move `sshd` from port 22 to some other free port bigger than 1024 or even bigger that 10000 to see what will happen then. If slowdown will be eliminated then  IPS is responsible for it.

Answer (score 3):

SSH is an interactive protocols, and so it sets a low TCP timeout. On a congested network, this can result in even more congestion, with dropped TCP packets due to timeout expire.

In the other hand, HTTP and other non-interactive protocols have more relaxed settings, privileging throughput at latency expense. On a congested network this can be more effective than the stricter timeout used by interactive protocols.

Comment: This is particularly problematic if you have a slow uplink (eg. I live in a country where ADSL (Asymmetric DSL) is used, the uplink speeds are very small in comparison to download. If someone is downloading something big, then the uplink gets saturated with the ACK traffic, and buffers tend to fill and SSH gets unusable. If you run the network with the slowest part, then you can shape traffic to control buffering and thus prioritisation. In the past, I've found WonderShaper (http://lartc.org/wondershaper/) very useful on a Linux router.